# Azure Function with Event Hub out binding does not work

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Function to send out message to multiple Event Hub outputs (from an input EH). My code is the following:

```
[FunctionName("Gateway")]
    public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("%INPUT_HUB_NAME%", Connection = "iothubconnection", ConsumerGroup = "functiontest")]EventData[] eventHubMessage,
        [EventHub("%OUT_HUB_NAME%", Connection = "eventhuboutput")]out EventData outputEventHubMessageHotPath,
        [EventHub("%OUT_HUB_NAME%", Connection = "eventhuboutput2")]out EventData outputEventHubMessageColdPath,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("**-- Start Azure Func -- **");


        foreach (var ehMsg in eventHubMessage)
        {
            //section to build up the raw section
            var rawMessageSection = GetPayload(ehMsg.GetBytes());
            var deviceId = GetDeviceId(ehMsg);
            log.Info($"Extracted deviceId: {deviceId}");
            if (rawMessageSection.aggregates != null)
            {
                var message = CreateEHMessages("aggregates", rawMessageSection, deviceId, log);

                outputEventHubMessageHotPath = message;
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath = message;
            }
            if (rawMessageSection.events != null)
            {
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath = CreateEHMessages("events", rawMessageSection, deviceId,  log);
            }
            if (rawMessageSection.ipis != null)
            {
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath = CreateEHMessages("ipis", rawMessageSection, deviceId, log);
            }
            if (rawMessageSection.errors != null)
            {
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath = CreateEHMessages("errors", rawMessageSection, deviceId,  log);
            }
            if (rawMessageSection.batteries != null)
            {
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath = CreateEHMessages("batteries", rawMessageSection, deviceId,  log);
            }
            //await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        outputEventHubMessageHotPath = outputEventHubMessageColdPath = null;
    }
```

where:

```
 public static EventData CreateEHMessages(string messageType, dynamic messageBatch, string deviceId, TraceWriter log)
    {
       var timezone = messageBatch.timezone;
        var deviceInstanceId = messageBatch.deviceInstanceId;
        int i = 0;
        List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (var msg in messageBatch[messageType])
        {

            msg.deviceId = deviceId;
            msg.timezone = timezone;
            msg.deviceInstanceId = deviceInstanceId;
            msg.type = messageType;

            result.Add(msg);
            i++;
        }
        var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)));
        eventData.PartitionKey = deviceInstanceId;
        return eventData;


    }
```

The problem is that this Function does NOT seem to publish to EventHub. I have tried to use different syntax of binding but i cannot get it to work.
I suspect is something to do with output bindings but I again tried many options.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `out` parameter multiple times, so all but the last assignments will be lost. But your last assignment is setting them to `null`, which essentially means you return no messages from your Function.

Have a look at `ICollector` instead.

Define your output parameters as Collectors:

```cs
[EventHub("%OUT_HUB_NAME%", Connection = "eventhuboutput")] 
ICollector<EventData> outputEventHubMessageHotPath,
```

Then add every message to the Collectors, e.g.:

```cs
if (rawMessageSection.events != null)
{
    outputEventHubMessageHotPath.Add(
        CreateEHMessages("events", rawMessageSection, deviceId,  log));
}
```

Comment: Actually i was just trying that. My function has changed a bit (as .csx). i am using now `public static void Run(EventData[] myEventHubMessage, ICollector<EventData> outputEventHubMessageHotPath, 
ICollector<EventData> outputEventHubMessageColdPath, TraceWriter log)` and indeed it work! Alongside I am adding every result in the Collector as you've suggested. @Mikhail thanks lot!

Comment: Just one more question. Compiler complains if i remove ` outputEventHubMessageHotPath = outputEventHubMessageColdPath = null;`. How can i initialize that? Remove it completely?

Comment: @toto Yes, remove it