# Azure Function with multiple output to same EventHub does not work

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have Azure Function with two output binding to Azure EventHub. Output are to same EH but different topics.
It works properly as long as the out message goes to one topic. If out goes to both topic i get error like:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.EventHubTriggerCSharp1. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter 
outputEventHubMessageColdPath after function returned:. Microsoft.ServiceBus:
This event data instance has already been disposed.
```

Although the message is sent to only 1 topics.
Do you have any idea why i cannot get message on both topics?
By the way code is related to:
[Azure Function with Event Hub out binding does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719837/azure-function-with-event-hub-out-binding-does-not-work/50723904#50723904)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved by changing from:

```
//Send it to both cold and hot path:
var message=CreateEHMessages("aggregates", rawMessageSection, deviceId, log);                  outputEventHubMessageHotPath.Add(message);
                outputEventHubMessageColdPath.Add(message);
```

to:

```
//Send it to both cold and hot path:
                    outputEventHubMessageHotPath.Add(CreateEHMessages("aggregates", rawMessageSection, deviceId, log));
                    outputEventHubMessageColdPath.Add(CreateEHMessages("aggregates", rawMessageSection, deviceId, log));
```